# Is "indifferent" a postpositive adjective in "leaves no one indifferent"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-position

Does this sentence contain a postpositive adjective?

> It leaves no one indifferent

I thought "indifferent" here is a postpositive adjective. Am I right?

Comment: Note that there's a double negative involved here, and _leave_ is a metaphor. This is not a garden-variety sentence.

Comment: So you mean it has an exception and it doesn't position as "predictive","attributive" or "postpositive"

Comment: I mean using this sentence as an example of anything is unlikely to improve anyone's understanding. And who says those are the only options?

Comment: I am just a curious learner. I only saw these three structure on the Internet. It can be more...

Comment: It's an object complement and a predicate adjective. Like this: *He painted the barn red.* *barn* = *red* due to the verb action.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective “indifferent” in that sentence just happens to come after “no one”, but is not attached to it. So it is not a postpositive adjective (which would be attached to the preceding material to form a phrase).

You can see this if you look at a related passive sentence: we would say “No one is left indifferent (by it)”, not *“No one indifferent is left (by it)”.

Comment: So what kind of an adjective is that ? It is not a predictative nor attributive..

Comment: @cerenaksengur: my memory of this kind of terminology is rusty, but I think it would be a predicative adjective used along with an object

Comment: @cerenaksengur It's a verbal argument, sometimes called a complement. It's not an adjunct. You can leave someone money and you get leave them excited. The only super-tiny problem is that when the final argument is an adjective it is very slightly ambiguous whether it applies to the subject argument or to the (first) "object" argument. But common sense normally applies.

Comment: @herisson: Yes, also called an object complement.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica thank you!